# Permutation Of 2 Groups

Tags: combinatorics

The Following question is from "A FIRST COURSE IN PROBABILITY" of Sheldon Ross

> A class in probability theory consists of 6 men and 4 women.
>   
>  An examination is given,
>   and the students are ranked according to their performance. 
> Assume that no two
>   students obtain the same score.
>   
> (b) If the men are ranked just among themselves and the women just among themselves,
>   how many different rankings are possible?
>   
> Solution: 
>   (b) Since there are 6! possible rankings of the men among themselves and 4! possible
>   rankings of the women among themselves, it follows from the basic principle that
>   there are (6!)(4!) = (720)(24) = 17,280 possible rankings in this case.

Why should not it be $(6!)(4!)(2!)$ as there are $2!$ ways to order the 2 groups?

Comment: We are not ranking the women's group against the men's group. They're just ranked separately.

Comment: It does not matter wether the men are listed above the women or vice versa. If it did, then you would be right.

Comment: @Arthur so the can be a man ranked 1th and a woman ranked 1th at the same time? but it says that "Assume that no two students obtain the same score"

Comment: But it also says "Assume the men are ranked just among themselves and the women just among themselves". That does not mean that all women ends up above all the men or vice versa. It means there one list containing all the men, and one list containing all the women.